# Mostrar solo un PHP de datos

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Estoy creando un proyecto donde tengo varios restaurantes en una base de datos, filtre solo aquellos que estén con el valor "ac" en la columna "activoar" dejo parte de mi codigo:

```html
<?php
$inc = include("conexion.php");
if ($inc){
    $consulta = "SELECT idRestaurante, Nombre, img, Telefono,coordenadas FROM restaurantes WHERE activoar='ac'";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conex,$consulta);
    if ($resultado){
        while($row= $resultado->fetch_array()){
            $idRestaurante = $row['idRestaurante'];
            $Nombre = $row['Nombre'];
            $img = $row['img'];
            $Telefono = $row['Telefono'];
            $coordenadas = $row['coordenadas'];

            ?> 
            <table>
            <tbody class="list">
            <tr>
                <td>
                <a href='#'>
                  <img  src="data:image/png;base64," width=150 height=100>  <?php echo base64_encode ($img); ?>

                </a>
                </td>
                <td class="name" ><b><center>
                <?php echo $Nombre; ?>
                </center></b>
                <div><center>
                    <a>

                    </a>
                </center>

                </div>
                <div>
                    <center>
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <a href="tel:<?php echo $Telefono ?>"> <img src="images/restaurants/phone icon4.jpg" width=25 height=25></a>
                                </td>
                                <td></td><td></td>
                                <td>
                                <a href="href:<?php echo $coordenadas ?>">   <img src="images/restaurants/maps.jpg" width=25 height=25></a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </center>
                </div>

                </td>
            
            </tr>
            </table>

            <?php

        }
    }
}
?>
```

Estoy tratando de hacer que al apretar el restaurante en <a href '#'> genere un php de sus categorías de cada restaurante dejo mi llamada sql:

> SELECT DISTINCT Categorias.Nombre FROM Categorias LEFT JOIN platillos
> ON platillos.idCategoria = Categorias.idCategoria WHERE
> platillos.idRestaurante=12

Esta llamada me trae los restaurantes dependiendo de su id y como resultado me entrega las categorias pertenecientes a ese restaurant y las imprime en pantalla.
pero quiero hacerlo de manera automatica, que en vez de poner el 12 manualmente,sea que al apretar el restaurante mande el idRestaurante por una variable y genere categorias.php pero de acuerdo a su id.

Comment: ¿Solo estas utilizando php? Invita al juego a JavaScript y empieza a realizar peticiones **AJAX** con **fetch** agrega un evento de tipo click al href optienes el id de cada restaurante y realizas tu consulta, puedes mostrarlo en un modal, quedaria mejor y sin que la pagina recargue, o si quieres hacerlo solo con PHP puedes capturar el valor del href con GET.

Comment: tendrías algún ejemplo o blog que me pudieras pasar por favor?